# overflow auto hover issue

Tags: css

I have a issue with overflow: auto; on child element. When i hover .wrapper class for divs its ruin divs' position. Check this out:
How can I deal with that? It will be great if the divs element would stay at the same place before hovering.

[http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQQLMJ?editors=110][1]

```
<div class="parent">
  <span class="close"></span>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti consequatur ipsum at temporibus veritatis soluta perspiciatis quisquam fugiat odit quibusdam nihil sapiente vero, reiciendis adipisci non reprehenderit aut similique deleniti repellendus doloremque esse. Officia, quam ullam atque iusto lorem80 accusantium vitae cumque earum incidunt quos voluptatum maxime ut, sunt mollitia. Sit impedit porro sunt beatae quae at, cupiditate ut, ipsa placeat maiores! Doloremque perspiciatis saepe animi iste numquam, consectetur rerum tempora minima, placeat asperiores harum explicabo necessitatibus delectus dolorem sit quidem.</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium esse ab nesciunt ipsa, vitae repellendus consectetur aperiam illum. Consequatur, dicta officiis adipisci minus, et tenetur assumenda repudiandae id, possimus, blanditiis mollitia repellendus. Nihil id doloribus culpa consectetur molestias voluptates iure blanditiis, at iusto cupiditate natus voluptatibus deleniti ab reprehenderit cumque eveniet soluta dolor officia incidunt recusandae, omnis. Quam facilis ducimus fugiat, nemo magni fuga, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae minima facilis, placeat, rerum quidem, possimus maxime accusantium beatae explicabo incidunt quasi rem atque tempora adipisci! Cumque sit ut iure suscipit. dolorum, perferendis tempore quod tenetur sequi aut eveniet. In, eius nam consequatur ipsam consequuntur fugiat a.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add width it works.

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width:465px;
    &:hover {
    overflow: auto;
      width:482px;
}
```